# Fe and first difference in a regression table

Tags: regression, panel, stata

I am doing an analysis in Stata and I have a lot of different panel regressions (within, first-difference and random trend) and to see the results properly, I am using `eststo` and `esttab`.

My problem now is that to get the difference for first difference and the double difference for the random trend, I use `d.`varname and `d.d.`varname.
Stata then thinks that the differences are new variables and puts them in their own rows which becomes very difficult to read.

Has anyone an idea how I can get a regression table in which Stata sees varname, `d.`varname and `d.d.`varname as the same variable?

My regression looks like this:

```
 foreach v in a aa aaa aaaa{
 qui eststo: xtreg `v' b b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 i.year, fe cluster(xy)
 qui eststo: xtreg `v' b b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 i.year if c>d, fe cluster(xy)
 qui eststo: reg d.`v' d.b d.b1 d.b2 d.b3 d.b4 d.b5 i.year, cluster(xy)
 qui eststo: reg d.`v' d.b d.b1 d.b2 d.b3 d.b4 d.b5 i.year if c>d, cluster(xy)
 qui eststo: reg d.d.`v' d.d.b d.d.b1 d.d.b2 d.d.b3 d.d.b4 d.d.b5 i.year, cluster(xy)
 qui eststo: reg d.d.`v' d.d.b d.d.b1 d.d.b2 d.d.b3 d.d.b4 d.d.b5 i.year if c>d, cluster(xy)
 esttab using output.tex, wide
 }
```

In my table I then get my estimates for

```
 b
 b1
 b2
 b3
 b4
 b5
 d.b1
 d.d.b1
 d.b2
 d.d.b2
 and so on..
```

Comment: The eststo command actually can do that quite easily. I add an example how to deal with that problem:
esttab,compress nogaps drop( monthdummy*   )  ///
 indicate( "Time Effects = yeardummy*"   ) ///
 rename(    D.Pre1Q Pre1Q D2.Pre1Q Pre1Q    D.Pre2Q Pre2Q D2.Pre2Q Pre2Q       ///
 D.Pre3Q Pre3Q D2.Pre3Q Pre3Q    )   ///
 b(%7,4f) se(%6.4f) /*stats(N ar2 )*/ scalars("N Observations" "N_clust Cities" "AvgTime Avg Time" "r2_a Adjusted  \(R^{2}\)" ) sfmt(%4,0f %4,0f %5,2f %5,4f) star(+ 0.1 * 0.05 ** 0.01  *** 0.001) ///

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit hacked together--ultimately it doesn't do anything fancy but just automates the changing of variable names across specifications. It seems a bit too much code for such a simple question, but I don't know of an easier way to do this.

```
***create dummy data
set seed 99
webuse xtsetxmpl, clear
foreach i in "" 1 2 3 4 5 {
    g b`i' = uniform()
    }
foreach i in a aa aaa aaaa c d {
    g `i'= y*uniform()
    }
*next two lines just so the differencing works
g xy = pid
replace tod = (tod-1609570800000)/(36*100000)
xtset pid tod
***end of data creation

cap program drop diff
program define  diff
syntax anything
cap drop *_adj *adjDV
if "`anything'" == "orig" {
foreach i in "" 1 2 3 4 5 {
    g b`i'_adj = b`i'
    }
foreach i in a aa aaa aaaa {
    g `i'_adjDV = `i'
    }
}
else {
foreach i in "" 1 2 3 4 5 {
    g b`i'_adj = `anything'b`i'
    }
foreach i in a aa aaa aaaa {
    g `i'_adjDV = `anything'`i'
    }
}
 end
 **************************************
 *run original regression (excluding year term not necessary to example)
 **************************************
 eststo clear
 foreach v in a aa aaa aaaa {
 diff orig
 eststo: xtreg `v'_adjDV *adj , fe cluster(xy)
 eststo: xtreg `v'_adjDV *adj  if c>d, fe cluster(xy)
 diff d.
 eststo: reg `v'_adjDV *adj , cluster(xy)
 eststo: reg `v'_adjDV *adj  if c>d, cluster(xy)
 diff d.d.
 eststo: reg `v'_adjDV *adj , cluster(xy)
 eststo: reg `v'_adjDV *adj  if c>d, cluster(xy)
 esttab _all, wide
 }
```

You are new here, so just for the future, try to post a MWE (minimal working example)---it makes things a bit quicker on this end. You can see that I have given an example of how to do this in the first section of the code.

Comment: For the record, this (good-looking) code won't work unless you have installed `eststo` and `esttab`.

Comment: Thank you SOConnell, but when I try to use my real data I always get the error "b not found" (I renamed my variables to b1 (b2...)), so I did not change your code at all.

Do you have an idea what could go wrong?

Comment: @Jacob I think you need to provide more information than `b not found`. At least describe the commands preceding the error. If the error occurred in the loop or stemmed from SOConnell's nice program `diff`, use `set trace on` to reveal the hidden codes.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works just using the esttab command. One example:

```
esttab ,compress nogaps booktabs drop( _cons) ///
 indicate("State specific effects = var_dummy_*") ///
rename(    D.b b D2.b b D.b2 b2 D2.b b2 )   ///
```

The rename gets the job done. The rest is included to show more possibilities.